# POP3 email in Gmail not filtering correctly

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, pop3

I am accessing another email account via POP3 within Gmail.

Update: I have 2 other email addresses set up with the same filters, and they are working as intended. The only difference between this filter which is not working correctly is that the account is accessed by POP3 from within gmail, whereas the other 2 accounts are gmail/google mail accounts which are forwarded to my gmail account.

I have the following filter set up:

> **Matches:** `to:(nick@domain.com), subject:("Question for") -followup.cc`
>   **Do this:** Apply label "Clients/ClientName", Never send it to Spam, Exclude from SmartLabel categorization

This filter is applying the label correctly to the right emails, but the label is also being applied to emails that contain `followup.cc`.

When I edit the filter or do a search for `to:nick@wavereview.com, subject:"Question for" -followup.cc"`, the search results contain only the correct emails, those that should be labelled and not those that shouldn't be (with `followup.cc`) in the email. So it appears the filter will work. But then each day all the emails that contain `followup.cc` are given the label as well.

The only other filter I have for this client is:

> **Matches:** `from:(reminder@followup.cc) to:(nick@domain.com)`
>   **Do this:** Skip Inbox, Apply label "Clients/ClientName-Follow Up", Never send it to Spam, Exclude from SmartLabel categorization

Comment: Is the "followup.cc" text in the `Doesn't have` box? So it shouldn't appear in the body of the email?

Comment: @w3d I've tried that and I get the same result. I've also tried `-followup.cc` in Has the words and also `-reminder@followup.cc` in the from field. All yield the same results

Comment: I have 2 other email addresses set up with the same filters, and they are working as intended. The only difference between this filter which is not working correctly is that the account is accessed by POP3 from within gmail, whereas the other 2 accounts are gmail/google mail accounts which are forwarded to my gmail account.